# Error cannot find symbol for function name

Tags: java

I am having a bit of a problem with a short part of my code, I have been hitting this particular code since morning so I may be a bit daft. Basically it compares the index of the array with another number in another class, this is the code and the error.

```
private static int encontrarCanal(int pbuscarCanal){

        int channelFound = -1;

        for(int i=0; i<numCanales; i++){
            if(canales[i].getCanal() == pbuscarCanal){
                channelFound = i;
                i = numCanales;
            }
        }

        return channelFound;
    }
```

In another class I have a simple:

```
 public int getCanal(){
     return canal;

 }
```

And the error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
            if(canales[i].getCanal(i) == pbuscarCanal){
                         ^
  symbol:   method getCanal()
  location: class String
1 error
```

I just need to patch that up to be done, so any help would be deeply appreciated.

EDIT:

Declaration of String Array canales:

```
static String[] canales = {"Channel1","Channel2","Channe3","Channel4"};
```

Tried doing:

```
static ArrayList<String> channel = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(canales));
```

But it gave a error:

```
  error: cannot find symbol
static ArrayList<String> channel = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(canales));
```

Comment: You may need to cast `canales[i]` to your class so that the method is visible in that scope. I.e. `((YourClass)canales[i]).getCanal();`

Comment: Where is the declaration of canales?

Comment: what your definition of canales, it is a String list?

Comment: @blurfus it won't work...

Comment: @andy added declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
symbol:   method getCanal()
location: class String
```

Your problem couldn't be expressed much more clearly than it is in this message: The `String` class does not have a method called `getCanal()`, and  `canales[i]` is a String, as per your declaration:  `static String[] canales = ...`.

In response to your updates, an `ArrayList<String>` is a list of `String` objects too, so calling `yourList.get(i).getCanal()` is no different than what you were doing before. Your problem is not the data structure you're using, it's what you're storing in it - Strings.

If the class that contains the `getCanal()` method is called `Foo`, then either of the following will compile:

```
  Foo[] canales = {...}
  ...
  canales[i].getCanal();

 //or: 
 ArrayList<Foo> canales = new ArrayList<>();
 ...add Foo objects 
 canales.get(i).getCanal();
```

will work. Note the difference between `List<String>` and `List<Foo>`, and read up on [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

In response to your comment, when you want to use/refer to one class from another, you need to either a) put them in the same [package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/package.html), or b) import one into the other by placing an `import` statement at the top of the latter, like so:

```
 package yourpackage;
 import otherpackage.Foo;
 //other imports...
 class ClassThatUsesFoo {
```

I don't know what your "similar situation earlier" was, but learning how classes/packages interact with one another is a very basic and important step to learning Java. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) would be a good place to start.

Comment: But getCanal() is in another class (file) and doing this worked for me in a similar problem earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Without the declaration of canales[], it's hard to say for sure, but it appears you're attempting to call getCanal() on a string object.

Comment: Added the information on the edit.